# download gzip file via php cURL

Tags: php, curl, gzip

I want to download file and save it.
I am using this code for downloading gzip file.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->_params['url']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$post = array("image_id"=>  $this->_response_id, "format"=>$this->_response_format);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But when I print type of result I am seeing string(i get  file with string format).

How can a resolve this problem?

Thank's

Comment: one note connected with my question:when I print ($info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);) I see image/svg+xml.@ goreSplatter ,i have forgotten to say you I 2 votes set you I for your comment(I know you love it :))

Answer (score 1):

you i think need to also include following option.

```
CURLOPT_ENCODING
```

it deals with the contents of the "Accept-Encoding: " header. This enables decoding of the response. Supported encodings are "identity", "deflate", and "gzip".

**p.s : start accepting answers or stop asking questions. maybe u also need to know** [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow)

ALSO check out [this](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42911) link and try using the patch.

Comment: i try all this options ,but result is same.

Comment: when I write thi : $info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);  
  curl_close($ch);
    echo '<br>'."type is :".'<br>'.$info;   I get type is :
image/svg+xml . And I don't understand what it is mean.